# Do Slater's rules apply to neutral lithium (at least approximately)?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electronic-configuration

For lithium, the electronic configuration is $\ce{(1s)^2(2s)^1}$. I tried to calculate $Z_{eff}$ for the $\ce{2s}$ orbital of the neutral atom as follows:

$$Z_{eff} = Z-\sigma$$
$$Z_{eff} = 3-(2\times0.3)$$
$$Z_{eff} = 2.4$$

But the Wikipedia article's table of effective nuclear charges (linked below) states that $Z_{eff}$ is 1.279 for the $\ce{2s}$ lithium orbital, which is not even close to my answer (above). So do Slater's rules not apply to lithium or I have done something wrong?

**Wikipedia article:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_nuclear_charge

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the factor of 0.85 for each of the $\ce{1s}$ electrons:
$$Z_{eff} = 3 - (2\times 0.85) = 1.3$$
as per rule #2 in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules):

> 2. If the group is of the [s p] type, an amount of 0.85 from each electron with principal quantum number n one less than that of the group, and an amount of 1.00 for each electron with principal quantum number two or more less.

The $\ce{1s}$ electrons both qualify as having "a principal quantum number $n$ one less than that of the group" (here, the principal quantum number of the group of the $\ce{2s}$ electron is 2). [Here is a nicely worked example for further edification](http://chemistry.umeche.maine.edu/~amar/spring2011/zeff.html).

Comment: So the screening of 1s orbital being 0.3 only applies to Helium?

Comment: The screening of a 1s electron by *another* 1s electron, as in the case of helium *can also apply to other atoms that are missing electrons that result in the $\ce{(1s)^2}$ electronic configuration* such as $\ce{Li+}$, where you calculate $Z_{eff} = 3 - (1\times 0.3) = 2.7$ (compare to 2.691 on Wikipedia's page on effective nuclear charge, linked in the main thread here).

Answer (score -3):

0.35 contribution of each of the other electrons in the same group excepting one .
0.85 contribution for each of the electrons in the nest inner group or immediately to the left. hence:
1s2 2s1
we except one
therefore 0.85*2=1.7
3-1.7=1.3 zeff=0.13
kindly note that there are other rules.